# React pass a prop that has an internally bound target

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a component in react that I'd like an element of which to be configurable. I'd like the consumer of the component to be able to configure the look and feel of the 'Inner component' and the 'SimpleComponent' to not expose the onClick function to the consumer as it is doing stuff internally.

Take this very simple example:

```
import React from 'react';

const SimpleComponent = ({ Inner }) => {

  const myBoundFunction = () => {
       alert('test');
  }

  return <div>test <Inner onClick={myBoundFunction} /> </div>;
};

export default SimpleComponent;
```

Inner:

```
import React from 'react';

const Inner = () => {
  return <a>Hi I'm the inner component!</a>;
};

export default Inner;


<SimpleComponent Inner={<InnerComponent/>} />
```

Is this possible? What should my approach be?

Comment: In your API, do you demand `Inner` to implement an `onClick`?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function component (`() => <>...</>`), and not a React element (`<Component/>`)

```
const SimpleComponent = ({ innerComponent: InnerComponent }) => {
  const myBoundFunction = () => {
    alert("test");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      inner has onClick <InnerComponent onClick={myBoundFunction} />

      {/* Or */}
      <div onClick={myBoundFunction}>
        inner doesn't have onClick
        <InnerComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Inner = ({ onClick }) => {
  return <a onClick={onClick}>Hi I'm the inner component!</a>;
};

// Think if your API should handle this case
const InnerNoOnClick = () => {
  return <a>Hi I'm the inner component!</a>;
};

<SimpleComponent innerComponent={Inner} />;
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]